# Can't seem to set up url encoding for the Prototype parameters that link_to_remote creates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prototype

I've been struggling for the past 2 hours to set up url encoding with rails' link_to_remote method.

I'm supposed to be able to submit a user-entered mobile phone number but in the '+4412323424' format.

At present the '+' does not get encoded and as a result the controller receives a white space instead of the '+'.

I've been working with Rails for a while now but I still have many things I need to wrap my head around...

> <%= link_to_remote "Add", {:update => 'employees', :url => {:action => 'add_mobile'}, :with => "'employee_mobile = ' + escape($('enter_mobile').value)"}, :class => 'btn_search' %>

This is the HTML that gets generated:

> `<`a onclick="new Ajax.Updater('employees', '/sms/add_mobile', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, parameters:'employee_mobile = ' + escape($('enter_mobile').value)}); return false;" href="#" class="btn_search"`>`Add`<`/a`>`

I'm assuming it has to be the parameters within Ajax.Updater that are incorrect?

Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your parameters is supposed to be an object of objects.

You want it to be something like this:

```
parameters: { employee_mobile: escape($('enter_mobile').value }
```

so try this (I am unfamiliar with rails syntax so i'm guessing a bit here):

```
<%= link_to_remote "Add", {:update => 'employees', :url => {:action => 'add_mobile'}, 
:with => "'employee_mobile:' + escape($('enter_mobile').value)"}, 
:class => 'btn_search' %>
```